# failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group ""

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-helm

I am trying to deploy my web-application into rancher kubernetes cluster via gitlab CI/CD pipeline. For that I use below helm command.

Note: I have only added the relevant jobs here not full .gitlab-ci.yaml file here.

```
.deploy:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    IMAGE_TAG: $CI_COMMIT_SHA
    NAMESPACE: webapp-${ENV}
  script:
    - >
      helm upgrade --install -n ${NAMESPACE} --create-namespace webapp ./helm -f helm/values.yaml --wait
      --set backend.image="${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/backend"
      --set backend.tag="${IMAGE_TAG}"
      --set frontend.image="${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/frontend"
      --set frontend.tag="${IMAGE_TAG}"

.helm-apply:
  stage: deploy
  image: 
      name: alpine/helm:3.13.3
      entrypoint: [""]
  before_script:
    - mkdir -p ~/.kube/
    - echo "$KUBECONFIG_B64" | base64 -d > ~/.kube/config
    - chmod 600 -R ~/.kube
  tags:
    - docker

helm-lint-dev:
  extends: 
    - .shared-helm-lint
  needs:
    - build:branch

helm-template-dev:
  extends: 
    - .shared-helm-template
  needs:
    - build:branch

deploy-helm-dev:
  extends: 
    - .dev
    - .helm-apply
    - .deploy
  rules:
    - if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH && $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE != 'schedule'
    - when: manual
  needs:
    - helm-lint-dev
    - helm-template-dev
```

Once I run the gitlab pipeline, I get the error

> Error: query: failed to query with labels: secrets is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:gitlab-runner:default" cannot list resource "secrets" in API group "" in the namespace "webapp-dev"

I have defined all the variables in gitlab CI/CD variables including the base64 encoded version of Kubeconfig file.

Note: When I test this locally using minikube, all works fine. So I guess there is no issue in the helm chart and the kubeconfig file and also in rancher cluster.

Any thoughts on this error and how to fix? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is inside of that kubeconfig file but from your error I guess its credential for `gitlab-runner` `serviceAccount`.

It does not matter if You are providing all variables to your helm release from your gitlab runner variables and variables file. Helm still needs to have access to secrets on target namespace since it is recording history of helm release in secrets. So at least, it has to be able to list secrets(I believe to check history) and create secrets(to save each release/upgrade).

Add these permissions to your gitlab-runner service account and check again.